# LMS hash calls formula?

Tags: hash-signature

If we consider LMS with (SHA256 and LMS-OTS as the OTS scheme) as defined in sections 5 and 4 here:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8554#section-5, they provide the following formulas for LMS-OTS (section 4.4):

In general, the LM-OTS signature is `4+n*(p+1)` bytes long,
and public key generation will take `p*(2^w - 1) + 1` hash computations
(and signature generation and verification will take approximately
half that on average)

So  ~ `(p*(2^w - 1) + 1)*(1/2) = total calls to SHA256` for sign
and the same is true for verify.

For a given parameter set of LMS as defined in Section 5, making use of LMS-OTS, what would those above formulas be?

For LMS parameter set:

Name              | H      | message digest m | height h
LMS_SHA256_M32_H15 | SHA256 | 32(bytes)        | 15      |

with Winternitz w = 8 which would use this LMS-OTS set:

| Parameter Set Name | H | n | w | p | ls | sig_len |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LMOTS_SHA256_N32_W8 | SHA256 | 32 (bytes) | 8 | 34 | 0 | 1124 |

Answer (score 1):

> for a given parameter set of LMS as defined in Section 5, making use of LMS-OTS, what would those above formulas be?

Well, for LMS verification, it would be the time taken for LMS-OTS verification, plus one hash [1] per Merkle tree height $L$ (which is either 5, 10, 15, 20 or 25).

On the other hand, for LMS signing, it's not as clear, as there are a number of possible ways to precompute Merkle tree state - the total time taken to generate the original public key is $2^L( p \cdot(2^w - 1) + 1 ) - 1$; however depending on how much state you save, it may be as small as $p\cdot(2^w-1)/2$ (assuming you save all the state), or as much as generating the original public key (assuming you don't save any of the state), or it might be circa $p\cdot(2^w-1)(k + 1/2)$ for some small $k$, assuming you use a Merkle tree walking algorithm.

---

[1]: Actually, because these hashes involve 2 SHA-256 compression operations, it is more precise to consider them two hashes; on the other hand, compared to the time taking to compute the Winternitz chains, the Merkle tree hashes can mostly be ignored)